# How can I get the text of a paragraph so I can then email it (vb.net)?

Tags: jquery, .net, vb.net

This is all VB.NET:

I am using jQuery to sum values selected through checking checkboxes. The jQ script writes the sum to a  tag with an id - "total".

```
<p id="total"></p>
```

How can I get the text of the paragraph with id "total" so I can then email it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write the sum to an `asp:hiddenfield`

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="myField" runat="server" />
```

in the codebehind you can access the hiddenfield value using it's ID

write the value to the hiddenfield using jquery:

```
$('#<%= myField.ClientID %>').val('myvalue');
```

Comment: Awesome. I removed the single quotes from "myvalue" and bingo. Thank you!